# Imprimir datos en una tabla

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos, html-tabla

buenas tengo una consulta el cual buscara los pagos de personas y mostrara en una tabla que mes pagaron y dejara en blanco o imprimira que ese mes no deposito, tengo el siguiente codigo, pero que quede pegado aqui para mostrar los pagos en su debido mes, es decir si pago en enero imprima en la td de enero y asi

```js
<div class="panel-body"> 
<div class="table-responsive"> 
<table id="tabla" style="table-layout:fixed" border="1" > 
<thead> 
<tr> 
<td width="2%">Propietario</td> 
<td>Enero</td> 
<td>Febrero</td> 
<td>Marzo</td> 
<td>Abril</td> 
<td>Mayo</td> 
<td>Junio</td> 
<td>Julio</td> 
<td>Agosto</td> 
<td>Septiembre</td> 
<td>Octubre</td> 
<td>Noviembre</td> 
<td>Diciembre</td> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody id="tbody"> 
<tr> 
<td>&nbsp;</td> 
<?php 
require_once('../conexion.php'); 
for($x=1;$x<=12;$x++){ 
$mes=mktime(0,0,0,$x,1,date("Y")); 
$fechai=date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0,$x,1,date("Y"))); 
$fechaf=date("Y-m-d",mktime(23,59,59,$x,date("t",$mes),date("Y"))); 
$sql = "SELECT montod, nombre, apellido, fechadeposito FROM pago_p WHERE DATE(fechadeposito) BETWEEN '".$fechai."' AND '".$fechaf."' GROUP BY nombre "; 
$res = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql); 
while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){} 
?> 
<td><?=$fechai?> <?=$fechaf?></td> 
<?php 
} 
?> 
</tr>
</tbody> 
</table> 
</div> 
</div>
```

Esto fue lo maximo que logre hacer pero aun si el resultado esperado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Posible duplicado https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/195126/imprimir-fechas-en-tabla

Comment: Pues no he podido resolverlo, busco a ver si alguien me orienta a terminarlo

Comment: Tienes una solución textual en el post original :)

Comment: si ya intente de todo pero aun lo maximo que muestra es cuadros vacios

Comment: El problema parece que lo tienes en tu base de datos, revisa que los SQL que estas enviando en este script en realidad funcionen en tu modelo de datos

Comment: el sql no ha cambiado es el mismo desde que inicio el problema, porque me muestra los datos, el error me da aquiwhile($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){} 
?> 
<td><?=$fechai?> <?=$fechaf?></td> 
<?php 
} 
?> 
</tr>

Comment: https://imageshack.com/a/img922/4365/wsLOYy.png foto de la base de datos de pago_p

Comment: Pues ahora entiendes porque obtienes lo mismo? siempre pruebas la misma SQL, observa el post original agregue una imagen con la captura de pantalla

Comment: @AndersonRey quedo bien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despues de mucho, dar vueltas, esta ya es la solucion a tu codigo particular.

```
<div class="panel-body"> 
<div class="table-responsive"> 
<table id="tabla" style="table-layout:fixed" border="1" > 
    <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <td width="2%">Propietario</td> 
            <td>Enero</td> 
            <td>Febrero</td> 
            <td>Marzo</td> 
            <td>Abril</td> 
            <td>Mayo</td> 
            <td>Junio</td> 
            <td>Julio</td> 
            <td>Agosto</td> 
            <td>Septiembre</td> 
            <td>Octubre</td> 
            <td>Noviembre</td> 
            <td>Diciembre</td> 
        </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody id="tbody"> 

            <?php 
            require_once('../conexion.php'); 

  $ene="No Pago"; $feb="No Pago"; $mar="No Pago"; $abr="No Pago"; $may="No Pago"; $jun="No Pago"; $jul="No Pago"; $ago="No Pago"; $sep="No Pago"; $oct="No Pago"; $nov="No Pago"; $dic="No Pago"; 

                $mes=mktime(0, 0, 0, $x, 1, date("Y")); 
                $fechai=date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,$x,1,date("Y"))); 
                $fechaf=date("Y-m-d", mktime(23,59,59,$x,date("t",$mes),date("Y"))); 
                //traes los nombre individualiza la consulta por persona
                $sql = "SELECT nombre, apellido FROM pago_p WHERE DATE(fechadeposito) BETWEEN '".$fechai."' AND '".$fechaf."' GROUP BY nombre "; 
                $res = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql); 
                //de pendendiendo de cuantas personas trae hace el ciclo
                while($resultado1 = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                    //almacenas los nombres y apellido en variables para hacer consulta para cada persona
                    $nombre = $resultado1['nombre'];
                    $apellido = $resultado1['apellido'];
                    //consulta esa persona cuntos pago hizo en el rango que tienes
                    $sql2 = "SELECT montod, fechadeposito FROM pago_p WHERE DATE(fechadeposito) BETWEEN '".$fechai."' AND '".$fechaf."' AND nombre = $nombres AND apellido = $apellido"; 
                        $res2 = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql); 
                        //ejemplo segun veo esta se hara 2 veces
                        while($resultado2 = mysqli_fetch_array($res2)){
                            //divides la fecha que trae la consulta y capturas el mes $valor[1]
                            $valor= explode('-', $resultado2['fechadeposito']);
                            //evaluas con un switch para ver a que mes corresponde y le das el nuevo valor que es el moto del pago
                            switch ($valor[1]) {
                                case '01':
                                    $ene = $result2['montod'];
                                    break;
                                case '02':
                                    $feb = $result2['montod'];
                                    break;
                                case '03':
                                    $mar = $result2['montod'];
                                    break;
                                case '04':
                                    $abr = $result2['montod'];
                                    break;
                                case '05':
                                    $may = $result2['montod'];
                                    break;
                                case '06':
                                    $jun = $result2['montod'];
                                    break;
                                case '07':
                                    $jul = $result2['montod'];
                                    break;
                                case '08':
                                    $ago = $result2['montod'];
                                    break;
                                case '09':
                                    $sep = $result2['montod'];
                                    break;
                                case '10':
                                    $oct = $result2['montod'];
                                    break;
                                case '11':
                                    $nov = $result2['montod'];
                                    break;
                                case '12':
                                    $dic = $result2['montod'];
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        //imprimer los 12 td que traeran 'no pago' por defecto y si encontro un pago tendra el monto
          echo "<tr>"; 
          echo "<td>$nombre $apellido</td>"; 
          echo "<td>$ene</td>"; 
          echo "<td>$feb</td>"; 
          echo "<td>$mar</td>"; 
          echo "<td>$abr</td>"; 
          echo "<td>$may</td>"; 
          echo "<td>$jun</td>"; 
          echo "<td>$jul</td>"; 
          echo "<td>$ago</td>"; 
          echo "<td>$sep</td>"; 
          echo "<td>$oct</td>"; 
          echo "<td>$nov</td>"; 
          echo "<td>$dic</td>"; 
          echo "</tr>"; 
          //reinicia lo valores
          // iniciarValores($meses);
          $ene="No Pago"; $feb="No Pago"; $mar="No Pago"; $abr="No Pago"; $may="No Pago"; $jun="No Pago"; $jul="No Pago"; $ago="No Pago"; $sep="No Pago"; $oct="No Pago"; $nov="No Pago"; $dic="No Pago"; 
                } 
                ?> 
        </tr>
    </tbody> 
</table> 
</div> 
</div>
```

poco elegante, pero 100% funcional. :)